# code -first Entity framework - Is this possible with inheritance and navigation properties?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I haven't been able to figure this one out.

```
public abstract class A
{
    public int property1 { get; set; }
    public int property2 {get; set; }
}

public class B : A
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public IList<C> C { get; set; }

}

public class C : A
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int AId { get; set; }

    public int dummyproperty {get; set; }

    public int BId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BId")]
    public virtual B B { get; set; }
}
```

How can I have my database context build these 2 tables using these class B and C?

Comment: what is the issue? I tested your classes in my VS2015 and it works ok. Can you provide more details about the error or difficulty?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var context = new MyContext();
            foreach(var b in context.Bs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(b.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<C> Cs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<B> Bs { get; set; }
    }
```

And then in Package Manager Console, run commands:
enable-migrations
add-migration Initial
update-database

And then add some records for B and C in file 'Configuration.cs' method Seed.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure where my problem lied. I was able to get it.